# Add more descriptive labelling to x-axis of Matplotlib histogram in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, histogram, distribution

I have created a histogram in a Jupyter notebook to show the distribution of time on page in seconds for 100 web visits.

Code as follows:

```
ax = df.hist(column='time_on_page', bins=25, grid=False, figsize=(12,8), color='#86bf91', zorder=2, rwidth=0.9)

ax = ax[0]
for x in ax:

    # Despine
    x.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    x.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    x.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

    # Switch off ticks
    x.tick_params(axis="both", which="both", bottom="off", top="off", labelbottom="on", left="off", right="off", labelleft="on")

    
    # Draw horizontal axis lines
    vals = x.get_yticks()
    for tick in vals:
        x.axhline(y=tick, linestyle='dashed', alpha=0.4, color='#eeeeee', zorder=1)

    # Set title
    x.set_title("Time on Page Histogram", fontsize=20, weight='bold', size=12)

    # Set x-axis label
    x.set_xlabel("Time on Page Duration (Seconds)", labelpad=20, weight='bold', size=12)

    # Set y-axis label
    x.set_ylabel("Page Views", labelpad=20, weight='bold', size=12)

    # Format y-axis label
    x.yaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:,g}'))
```

This produces the following visualisation:

[image]

I'm generally happy with the appearance however I'd like for the axis to be a little more descriptive, perhaps showing the bin range for each bin and the percentage of the total that each bin constitutes.

Have looked for this in the Matplotlib documentation but cannot seem ot find anything that would allow me to achieve my end goal.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `bins=25`, 25 equally spaced bins are set between the lowest and highest values encountered. If you use these ranges to mark the bins, things can be confusing due to the arbitrary values. It seems more adequate to round these bin boundaries, for example to multiples of 20. Then, these values can be used as tick marks on the x-axis, nicely between the bins.

The percentages can be added by looping through the bars (rectangular patches). Their height indicates the number of rows belonging to the bin, so dividing by the total number of rows and multiplying by 100 gives a percentage.  The bar height, x and half width can position the text.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time_on_page': np.random.lognormal(4, 1.1, 100)})
max_x = df['time_on_page'].max()
bin_width = max(20, np.round(max_x / 25 / 20) * 20) # round to multiple of 20, use max(20, ...) to avoid rounding to zero
bins = np.arange(0, max_x + bin_width, bin_width)
axes = df.hist(column='time_on_page', bins=bins, grid=False, figsize=(12, 8), color='#86bf91', rwidth=0.9)
ax = axes[0, 0]
total = len(df)
ax.set_xticks(bins)
for p in ax.patches:
    h = p.get_height()
    if h > 0:
        ax.text(p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2, h, f'{h / total * 100.0  :.0f} %\n', ha='center', va='center')
ax.grid(True, axis='y', ls=':', alpha=0.4)
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
for dir in ['left', 'right', 'top']:
    ax.spines[dir].set_visible(False)
ax.tick_params(axis="y", length=0)  # Switch off y ticks
ax.margins(x=0.02) # tighter x margins
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yep! This is superb, Johan. Thank you kindly for taking the time to answer and provide guidance. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: followup question - If I now wanted to change the bin ranges to say 10 as opposed to 20, what would have to modify in the following? 

bin_width = max(20, np.round(max_x / 25 / 20) * 20)

Comment: `bin_width = max(10, np.round(max_x / 25 / 10) * 10)` would round to multiples of 10.  The 10 in `max(10, ...` just sets a minimum value (to avoid zero widths). The division by 25 makes `bin_width` about 1/25 th of the total width. The division by 10, rounding and multiplying again by the same value results in rounding to a mutliple of 10.  Note that for powers of 10, this is the same as `bin_width = max(10, np.round(max_x / 25, -1))`  where `-1` means rounding to `-1` digits after to decimal point.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I tried to validate the methodology using the histogram function in Excel (which is what I would've used were it not for Python) and I get entirely different results for the % labels when choosing bin ranges of the same size as in your methodology. Probably about 8-10% points higher in Excel in most cases for the same dataset as created in Pandas using ```df = pd.DataFrame({'time_on_page': np.random.lognormal(4, 1.1, 100)})```
Are you able to validate at all?

Comment: Just sum up all the percentages. If everything works well, the sum should be 100 (up to some possible rounding error, but in case there are exactly 100 rows there wouldn't be any rounding). Also, in my example code the bins are 20 wide, but you can really choose any number. You even don't need to round the binwidths if the only goal is to see the percentages (the ticks will be harder to read though).

Comment: Thanks again. Just a little perplexed as to why, when using your methodology and I have ~13.5k occurrences of an integer value between 90-100 in ~740k rows, these are not represented in the histogram. I would expect to see a correspoding bin with label 1.82% (13.5k/740k )

Comment: With integer values you have to be very careful with the values on the boundaries. The implementation of pandas hist seems to put the values 90 till 99 in the bin 90-100 and 100 in bin 100-110.  You can change this behavior, e.g. creating the bins as `bins = np.arange(0.00001, ...)` would put 90 in bin 80-90 and 100 in bin 90-100 (but also would put 0 in bin -10,0 which isn't shown).

Comment: Makes sense Johan.
I think any anomalies in the histogram were probably artefacts of unclean data. I removed NULLS and did some more integrity checks and subsequently the bin ranges and distributions now makes a lot more sense. Thanks again for your time and tutelage.